# Display user inputted name with html and php

Tags: php, html, web, html-helper

I had my code working earlier today, with first asks for your name with html and then generated a "Hello -username- -surname-" message with php. I was trying to adjust the indentation and i think i must have erased something that now makes it simply display the code... Thanks for the help!

The html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">

        <title>form 11 29</title> </head>

        <body>

        <form method="post" action="process1.php" name="form1">
        Name : <input name="firstname" value=""><br>
        Surname : <input name="surname"> 
        <input name="s1" value="Submit LoL !" type="submit"><br>

        <br>
        <br>


        </form>

<br>

</body>
</html>
```

The php page:

```
<?php

        $name = $_POST[firstname];

        $surname = $_POST[surname];


        echo "Hello "; 

        echo $name;

        echo "&nbsp";

        echo $surname;

        echo "<br />";


?>
```

Comment: `< ? php` --- is it the exact code you've written? With spaces? If so - I have bad news for you...

Comment: No, but when I inputted it normally it displayed as a bunch of asterisks on the previewer so typing it out like this was the only way. I am profoundly sorry

Comment: please edit your post to show us the **exact** code, without any extra-spaces and other symbols that is not in your original code. BTW, have you looked at the error log? Also it is a good practice to develop using `display_errors` directive turned on with `E_ALL` errors level

Comment: @colle - That's because you didn't use a code block. I fixed it for you...

Comment: i don't know what those last things are but i edited the code

Comment: I have MAMP running with an Apache and MySQL server (I'm not using the mysql server yet,just saying that I have it up and running). What is happening is that when I write a first and last name into the HTML form, the php script instead of running is being displayed as raw code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It work for me (sort of). It gives this output

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant firstname - assumed 'firstname' in F:\Dropbox\htdocs\process1.php on line 3

Notice: Use of undefined constant surname - assumed 'surname' in F:\Dropbox\htdocs\.php on line 5
Hello Joe Blow
```

Because you forgot to put quotes around the indices to $_POST, which should be

```
  $name = $_POST['firstname'];
  $surname = $_POST['surname'];
```

Btw - now you have leanred the value of backups. Use a VCS (or, use Dropbox whch will keep old vesions for you (hmmm, irrc, if you develop in Netbeans it will also keep old versions and let you diff them with the current version))

---

Udate: are you uploading to a website or runing on your own PC? If your own PC then perhaps your web server (Apache or ISS) stopped runing?

You asked abotu NetBeans: take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans and http://netbeans.org/features/php/  Netbeans is an excellent free IDE (partly developed and supported by Sun) which is my developmnent platform of choice as a professional PHP developer (and I am not alone). Give it a try; I doubt that you will look back.

Comment: what is netbeans i am using dreamweaver and coda, with finder as my version control haha

Comment: hey it is not working for me! It just displays the code in both Safari and in chrome it downloads the php file as a .php file

Comment: It should ask for your first and last name and then display them like "Hello John Smith"

Comment: Fixed it. I didn't go to my localhost on the browser

Comment: Great (can I have the answer, pelase ;-)